# Insert Char at specific position in string Erlang

Tags: erlang, number-formatting

I wish to insert a *character* at a *specific position* in the string in **Erlang**.

**Eg**. Suppose i wish to insert "," in string "123456789" at position 3,5,7.

```
123456789 ~> 12,34,56,789
```

Any help Appreciated!! Thanks :)

Comment: in any case would be better if you in next time provide code with your attempt for solve problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solutions require that the positions list be sorted low to high:

1) **To insert a single character string**:

```
insert_test() ->
    "a,b" = insert(",", "ab", [2]),
    ",a"  = insert(",", "a", [1]),
    "ab"  = insert(",", "ab", [3]),
    "a,b,c" = insert(",", "abc", [2,3]),
    all_tests_passed.

insert([InsertChar], String, Positions) ->
    insert(InsertChar, String, Positions, 1, []).

insert(InsertChar, [Char|Chars], [Index|Ps], Index, Acc) ->
    insert(InsertChar, Chars, Ps, Index+1, [Char,InsertChar|Acc]);
insert(InsertChar, [Char|Chars], Ps, Index, Acc) ->
    insert(InsertChar, Chars, Ps, Index+1, [Char|Acc] );
insert(_, [], _, _, Acc) ->
    lists:reverse(Acc).
```

2) **To insert a random length string**:

```
insert_test() ->
    "a,b" = insert(",", "ab", [2]),
    ",a"  = insert(",", "a", [1]),
    "a--b" = insert("--", "ab", [2]),
    "--ab" = insert("--", "ab", [1]),
    "a--b--c" = insert("--", "abc", [2,3]),
    all_tests_passed.

insert(InsertStr, Str, Positions) ->
    insert(InsertStr, Str, Positions, 1, []).

insert(InsertStr, [Char|Chars], [Index|Ps], Index, Acc) ->
    insert(InsertStr, Chars, Ps, Index+1, combine(InsertStr, Char, Acc) );
insert(InsertStr, [Char|Chars], Ps, Index, Acc) ->
    insert(InsertStr, Chars, Ps, Index+1, [Char|Acc]);
insert(_, [], _, Acc, _) ->
    lists:reverse(Acc).


combine_test() ->
    ",X" = lists:reverse( combine(",", $X, []) ),
    "a,X" = lists:reverse( combine(",", $X, "a") ),
    "ab--X" = lists:reverse( combine("--", $X, lists:reverse("ab") ) ),
    all_tests_passed.

combine([], X, Acc) ->
    [X|Acc];
combine([Char|Chars], X, Acc) ->
    combine(Chars, X, [Char|Acc]).
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead answer as finished solution I show how you easy could found it yourself.

A. Define input data - Str string for transforming, Pos - list with positions for insert.

```
simple_transform(Str,Positions)->
```

B. Split the problem on part. What we need? Iterate over list with getting element and index , apply function to them and detect if element in list. That's all. If you need work with list usually you will use module lists from standard library. Look into the [documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.htm) and looking for suitable function.

1. transform - it's [lists:map/2](http://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#map-2)
2. iterate(traversed from left to right) - it's [lists:foldl/2](http://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#foldl-3);
   But since the combination of these two operations are very popular also there is a function that does this. It is [lists:mapfoldl/2](http://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#mapfoldl-3)
3. detect - it's [lists:member/2](http://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#member-2);

Collect everything together:

```
simple_transform(Str,Positions)->
{List,_}=lists:mapfoldl(
fun(El,Acc)->case lists:member(Acc,Positions) of
    true ->{[$,,El],Acc+1};
    false ->{El,Acc+1} end end,1,Str),
 lists:flatten(List).
```

Answer (score 0):

If your looking to just transform a string into a very specific format:

```
insert_commas(String) ->
  string:join([string:substr(String, 1, 2), ",", string:substr(String, 3, 2), ",", string:substr(String, 5, 2), ",", string:substr(String, 7)], "").


module:insert_commas("123456789").` returns `"12,34,56,789"
```